# Understanding the "args" of HttpResponseRedirect in views.pyfile in Django

Tags: django, parameter-passing, httpresponse, args

I have these two functions in my views.py file:

```
def entry(request, title):
    if title not in util.list_entries():
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
            "error": "Page Not Found",
            "query": title
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "entry": markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title)),
            "title": title
        })


def search(request):
    if request.POST["q"] in util.list_entries():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("entry", args=(request.POST["q"],)))
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")
```

How we can understand the args of HttpResponseRedirect. Where this args passed in the entry function? I just need the behind the scene action of this "args".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url pattern has likely a parameter, for example:

```
path('entry/<str:item>/', some_view, name='entry'),
```

by using the `args=…` and `kwargs=…` parameters of the [**`reverse(…)`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse), you fill in the values for the parameter.

`args` expects an iterable of items, these are *positional* parameters. The `kwargs` expect a dictionary that maps strings to values, these are the *named* parameters.

With the given example for the `entry` path, if the request has a POST value *`foobar`*, it will thus construct a url `/entry/foobar/`.

It is however more convenient to use [**`redirect(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). This basically calls the `reverse`, and then wraps the result in a `HttpResponseRedirect`, but it uses itself positional and named parameters to fill in the values:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def search(request):
    q = request.POST.get('q')
    if q in util.list_entries():
        return redirect('entry', q)
    else:
        return render(request, 'encyclopedia/error.html')
```

Comment: Yes, understood. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation bro.

Comment: Willem, why are using "get" here in q = request.POST.get('q')?

Comment: @Fayzulla: because it is not sure that `request.POST` *has* a `q` object. In case no `q` item is present in the POST data, then using `request.POST['q']` will raise a `KeyError`, by using `.get('q')` it will return `None`.

Comment: It works only with request.POST["q"]. It raises TypeError if I add get. Why?

Comment: But did you use `request.POST.get(...)`, or `request.get`?

Comment: @Fayzulla: can you share the full traceback?

Comment: I have used `request.POST.get(...)`

Comment: @Fayzulla: can you provide the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224496/discussion-between-fayzulla-and-willem-van-onsem).